# How to Track Dynamic Links from Content Syndication

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am using following function for content syndication

```
SET @url = concat('http://xyz.com?{"ua":"_","ip":"_","ua_class":"auto","version":17, "data":{"zip":"', @zipCodeShort,'"},"api_token":"1234","placement_id":"5678"}')
 ]%%
```

And then HTTPGET function to retrieve content;

```
%%=httpget(@url)=%%
```

Now How Do I track the Clicks for URLs within content? I tried TreatAsContent function but it did not work. Also I used HTTPGetWrap but in this case the content can be visible when using SendPreview but when I send an email it's does not have content.

PLease help me understand what function I have to use to track Clicks on Links within Content Syndication?

Answer (score 0):

OK it's resolved by using

`TreatAsContentArea` function.

Comment: mark your answer as "Answer" to close the thread.